# Speech to Text to get previous word after saying another word Android

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech, words

I have a project using Speech to Text where you can text someone without typing and sending it via voice.
Now I have a code where the user says the words/sentence that he/she wants to send, and I also have a confirmation where the user needs to say YES to send.

Now my codes are

```
//Voice recording message via mic
public void promptSpeechInput() {
    //Create intent to recognize the speech and we have putExtra to have other values than voice itself
    Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Say something!");

    //StartActivityForResult always binded by intent, getting the result from previous intent


    try {
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You device does not support LazySpeech App", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Here is my **onActivityResult** code

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int request_code, int result_code, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(request_code, result_code, data);

    switch (request_code) {
        case 100:
            if (result_code == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                sampleTextView.setText(result.get(0));
                String getMessage = sampleTextView.getText().toString();
                messageHolder(getMessage);

                String getAnswer = sampleTextView2.getText().toString();

                switch(getAnswer){
                    case"yes":
                        ttsobject.speak("yes?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                        sampleTextView3.setText(getMessage);
                        break;
                    case"no":
                        ttsobject.speak("No?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }
    }

}
```

and Here is my confirmation text

```
public String messageHolder(String getMessage){

    if(getMessage != ""){
        if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("15")) {
            ttsobject.speak("You want to send this message".concat(getMessage) + "?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            activateMicButton();

        } else {
            ttsobject.speak("You want to send this message".concat(getMessage) + "?", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            activateMicButton();
        }

    }else{

        if (Build.VERSION.RELEASE.startsWith("15")) {
            ttsobject.speak("say your words again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null);
            activateMicButton();
        } else {
            ttsobject.speak("say your words again", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
            activateMicButton();

        }
    }

    return getMessage;
}
```

and for example he/she said
"Hey wanna have dinner?".

The question is, How can I get the words(Hey wanna have dinner) that he/she wants to send, because all I can get is the "YES" or "NO" text from my confirmation.

I have tried creating something like this

```
sampleTextView2.setText(result.get(1));
String getSentence = sampleTextView.getText().toString();
```

I also have tried making static string, put it in globalvariable,

and still no luck. the words kept changing everytime I say something on mic, 
anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: are you sure you have an internet connection?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.
tho it works with no internet and with internet connection

Answer (score 0):

You can save your previous words by just copying the string, not the pointer to it, like you did it with global variable. You can do it by creating new `String` object, using the following constructor:

```
String theWords = new String(result.get(0));
```

And then you can use `theWords` variable to get the message user wants to send.

Comment: Hello sorry it took me too long to reply. I was so and too busy with other things with work, I just got time to develop this.
I followed the new string now I can get the "yes" word (Thanks to you!), now the thing is, it is a text to speech, then when I say the "yes" word, the "sentence that I need to send now replaced by the word yes", I mean I can't get the previous words sentence before I said yes, because those words/sentences is I want to send. do you know how? coz it always replaced by the words that I said, I will accept this answer if you will reply hehe, Thank you so much anyways!